# Postgresql 13.9 pg_dump 12.12 server version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, backup, pg-dump

While taking the backup of the postgressql database I am getting below issue

```
pg_dump -Fc -h localhost -U postgres -d <user> -f <filename>`
pg_dump: error: server version: 13.9; pg_dump version: 12.12 (Ubuntu 12.12-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

Can anyone help me with this issue and help us to take the appropriate backup?

Comment: You need to update the Postgres client tools on the computer where you are running pg_dump to match the version on the database server.

Comment: Given this `pg_dump -Fc -h localhost ...` I have to believe you have the correct `pg_dump` version available on the machine. How was Postgres installed on the machine?

Comment: What does `dpkg -l | grep postgresql-client` return?

Comment: Hello @Adrian Klaver

I am getting below output
`ii  postgresql-client-12                  12.12-0ubuntu0.20.04.1            amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 12`

`ii  postgresql-client-common              214ubuntu0.1                      all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions`

Comment: Alright so you need to do  `sudo apt install postgresql-client-13`.  Then do `pg_dump --cluster 13/main -Fc -h localhost -U postgres -d <user> -f <filename>`. You probably also do `pg_lsclusters` at the command line to see what Postgres instances you have running.